# Swift user's authorization

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

everyone. I installed Swift 1.7.4 , and I want to add a new user to Swift, How could I do it? I find that in 1.4.8 version, somebody had said that I should install the swauth first and I notice that the Swift api also said that choose one authrize way, so I must install a authorization service first? I also find that there is a tempauth middleware in the proxy-server.conf file, could I use this to add user and how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can choose from swauth or tempauth. The most difference of these two auth systems is where they store user information.

Swauth stores user/password information in swift cluster itself. It uses a special container and store every user's information in it. Swauth provides a set of commands for user management such as `swauth-add-user`, `swauth-prep`, etc.

In tempauth, it stores user information in `proxy-server.conf`, so it is very easy to use. 
In your `proxy-server.conf`, enable tempauth in pipeline and put user information in tempauth section. For example,

```
[pipeline:main]
pipeline = healthcheck cache tempauth proxy-server

[filter:tempauth]
use = egg:swift#tempauth
user_admin_admin = admin .admin
user_hi_hihi = testing
```

Then you will have two users. One is `admin:admin` whose password is `admin`. The other is `hi:hihi` whose password is `testing`.

Comment: To quickly test TempAuth with user `test:tester` and password `testing`: `curl -v -H 'X-Storage-User: test:tester' -H 'X-Storage-Pass: testing' http://<swifthost>:8080/auth/v1.0`